# Is it possible to have a VBA script that will take URLs from hyperlinked images?

Tags: image, url, vba

I have a workbook full of text and image hyperlinks, I've got some code that will deal with the text URLs nicely, however, the image links are presenting a problem as they don't sit in the flow of the page to be able to pull those links. I don't know how VBA treats these as objects, is it possible to target or cycle through them to pull out their URLs?

Comment: Do I get you right- you have some shapes/images in the sheet. And there is hyperlink attached to each image? And you want to read the hyperlink address? For Shape(1) you could do it this way: `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.shapes(1).Hyperlink.Address`

Comment: Hi, that's exactly what I mean, thanks I think I'm getting closer - didn't know how to reference a shape. I've tried to turn this into a looping function with the code below however I'm getting 'Application defined or object defined error'. I'm assuming I've gone wrong with the reference to the shape again - any ideas?     
    Dim WriteRow As Integer 
    WriteRow = 1 
    Dim imglink As Shape 
    For Each imglink In Sheets(1).Shapes 
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(WriteRow, 1).Value = imglink.Hyperlink.Address 
    WriteRow = WriteRow + 1 
    Next

Comment: additional code looks fine... which line is the error? which number is the error??

Comment: Interesting! The error number is 400 and the description I'm getting is 'application defined or object defined error'. Sorry I don't know how to find the line of the error. Any ideas?

Comment: see proposed answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way (I used your code and put some error handling instructions):

```
Sub test()
    Dim WriteRow As Integer
    WriteRow = 1
    Dim imglink As Shape

'error handling
On Error Resume Next
For Each imglink In Sheets(1).Shapes
    'if any shape doesn't have hyperling we would skip it
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(WriteRow, 1).Value = imglink.Hyperlink.Address
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        WriteRow = WriteRow + 1
    Else
        Err.Clear
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I expect that you have an error each time you check Hyperlink for shape which doesn't have one.